# Page break changes after saving with Python's xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have a Excel file which is used as a template. If I open this file the page break is as follows. [page break template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ea70P.png)
After opening and saving this file using xlwings with the following script:

```
import xlwings

file = xlwings.Book("template.xlsm")
sheet = file.sheets["Blad1"]

file.save("test.xlsm")
```

When I check the page break of the saved file the page break has changed. [page break saved file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0rMO.png)

If I open the template manually and save it the page break will stay the same.

How can I use xlwings and keep the page breaks the same?

Comment: could you pls attach the images within the questions instead of having them as hyperlinks

Comment: I am not allowed yet. Sorry.

Comment: No issues I'm aware of with the latest releases. Are you running the latest or very recent version? Latest is now 0.28.8. You can [re]set the print area but if you do have problems with the latest xlwings, might need to raise with the devs.

Comment: I did use an older version. Thank you for letting me check this. Sadly I keep getting the same result after updating to version 0.28.8. I will try to contact the makers of xlwings.

Comment: I received the following reply:
"Have you tried to open the workbook and save manually to see if it behaves the same? xlwings doesn't do anything with regards to page break, this looks to me as if Excel itself is doing this. As a workaround, you can always read and re-assign the print area via: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.main.PageSetup.print_area"

The problem isn't solved but by explicitly setting the page breaks I am able to use the code.